# Is there a way to build a dynamic navigation/menu based on registered routes in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm currently struggling to find a way to build a dynamic navigation based on routes registered in the application.

As far as I see there is no simple way to get a list of all routes using `Router` or `RouteRegistry` classes.

But, there is a private `_rules` property inside of [RouteRegistry](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/router/route_registry.ts#L90) class, but unfortunately with no getter for it.

Is there any specific reason why I can't access this parameter outside the RouteRegistry?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the routes in an array outside of the component so you can pass it to `@RouteConfig(...)` and also load into your component and analyze it to generate the menu.

The router is currently reworked therefore things that currently aren't that easy might become better soon.